# how to add one column into more tables in mysqli?

Tags: php, mysqli

First I SELECT a table to read values from id column

```
$db_hand1 = mysqli_connect($server, "root", "password",$database1);
$result = mysqli_query($db_hand1, "SELECT id FROM table");
```

Now I want to add one column into tables in another database:

```
$db_hand2 = mysqli_connect($server, "root", "password",$database2);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $user_id= $row['id'];
    $result = mysqli_query($db_hand2,"ALTER TABLE $user_id ADD us_id INT( 1 ) NULL DEFAULT '1'");
}
```

However this **while** doesn't work. It always add a column into the first table. When I do it manualy:

```
$db_hand2 = mysqli_connect($server, "root", "password",$database2);
$user_id= "table_name";
$result = mysqli_query($db_hand2,"ALTER TABLE $user_id ADD us_id INT( 1 ) NULL DEFAULT '1'");
```

and manualy set **$user_id** for a name of table it works.

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: You are using `$result` for both the queries, change it to another variable maybe `$result2 = mysqli_query($db_hand2,"ALTER TABLE $user_id ADD us_id INT( 1 ) NULL DEFAULT '1'");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you override the `$result`, change like

```
$db_hand2 = mysqli_connect($server, "root", "password",$database2);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $user_id= $row['id'];
        $result_alter = mysqli_query($db_hand2,"ALTER TABLE $user_id ADD us_id INT( 1 ) NULL DEFAULT '1'");
    }
```